# emailData not appearing in email when user registers new account

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to send the administrator a new user notification email. The email sends however the new users first name, family name or phone number is passing through to the email and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

**Update**

The data that's not passing into the email is:

```
var emailData = { firstName: (user && user.profile && user.profile.firstName), familyName: (user && user.profile && user.profile.familyName), phone: (user && user.profile && user.profile.phone) };
```

Path:  `startup.js`

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    if (options.profile && options.profile.roles) {
      //include the user profile
      Roles.setRolesOnUserObj(user, options.profile.roles);
    }

    if (options.profile) {
      // include the user profile
      user.profile = options.profile;
    }

    // other user object changes...
    // ...

    user.accountStatus = { isUserAccountActive: false };


    // In your client code: asynchronously send an email
    Meteor.call('newUser');
    return user;
  });
```

Path: `email.js`

```
newUser: function () {
    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'newUserRegistration.html' ) );

    var user = Meteor.user();

    var emailData = {
      firstName: (user && user.profile && user.profile.firstName),
      familyName: (user && user.profile && user.profile.familyName),
      phone: (user && user.profile && user.profile.phone)
    };

    Email.send({
      to: "admin@myemail.com",
      from: "admin@myemail.com",
      subject: "New user registration",
      html: SSR.render( 'htmlEmail', emailData )
    });
  },
```

Comment: can you please rephrase your question, as I am unable to understand the question? I can't understand what problem you are facing. Thanks. I would definitely help you.

Comment: Thanks ankur. Does that help a little

Comment: Use console.log() before preparing emaildata to see what you are getting. Also attach screenshot of output that you get in console of chrome as well as meteor

Comment: { firstName: null, familyName: null, phone: null }  - is it because the user hasn't been created yet?

Comment: Yes. There is something wrong you are doing in the code. You must check user, user.profile, user.profile.firstname separately and also output console log in onCreateUser() to see user object created properly.

Comment: console.log(user.profile.firstname) and console.log(user.profile) display all the correct information. does my meteor.call need more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Pass a parameter into newUser function as user object.

```
 Meteor.call('newUser', user);
 newUser : function(user){}
```

Comment: That's weird, its not passing the parameter into the newUser function.

Comment: this is seriously weird. Just make that parameter names are same.

Comment: Yep its the same. Can you pass a parameter with meteor.call

Comment: Yes, I am able to pass parameters.

Comment: Ok, sorry. My fault. I had `var user = Meteor.user();` within the newUser so the user data was being overridden. Your solution works! Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are too kind :). But rather I should thank you, you raise problems, because of which I am able to dig through framework in much better way. Thanks a ton again.